# C# Coding issue with Drop Down List

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

First, let me tell you what error I am getting.

> 'DDLTesttoAppear' has a `SelectedIndex` which is invalid because it
>   does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

I have many enums in my project, Here two enums are related two this question. 
This Two enums are

```
public enum Gender
{
    NA = 0, Male = 1, Female = 2
}
```

and

```
public enum NumberOfAdmissionTest
{
    NA = 0, First = 1, Second = 2, Third = 3, Fourth =4
}
```

In UI page I have two DDls they are like

```
DDLGender.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Gender));
DDLGender.DataBind();

DDLTestApearnce.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(NumberOfAdmissionTest));
DDLTestApearnce.DataBind();
```

This fields can be inserted as null into the database. Therefore, while  returning the record I am using a null hander function 
where the line of code to execute is that

```
candidateEntity.CandidateGender = nullHandler.GetInt32(CANDIDATE_GENDER);
candidateEntity.TestToAppear = nullHandler.GetInt32(TEST_TO_APPEAR);

public int GetInt32(String sFieldName)
{
    return (_reader[sFieldName] == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : _reader.GetInt32(_reader.GetOrdinal(sFieldName));
}
```

After retrieving the record, I am binding this with two ddls like

```
DDLGender.SelectedIndex = candidateEntity.CandidateGender;
DDLTesttoAppear.SelectedIndex = candidateEntity.TestToAppear;
```

Now, the interesting or confusing, whatever you say, part of this problem is that for gender, it's not generating any error, but for test appearance it's generating the error.

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Comment: @Pankouri What error did you recieve?

Comment: You guys don misunderstood me, but the gender is not giving error, the is the DDLTestApearnce which is generating the error, and the error I have mentioned it in the first section of my question and I am giving it again. 'DDLTesttoAppear' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Comment: Where are you binding `DDLTesttoAppear`? Could it be that you're setting the selected value before binding it? Have you checked in the debugger that `candidateEntity.TestToAppear` is a valid value for the enum? Also, you are binding `GetNames`, but setting an integer value.

Comment: yes, while debuggin the line DDLTesttoAppear.SelectedIndex = candidateEntity.TestToAppear ; before executing, SelectedIndex holds the value -1 and at the same tome, candidateEntity.TestToAppear holds the value 0 (for null in the DB)

Comment: You say that there are two dropdownlists but I can see three names, DDLTestApearnce, DDLTesttoAppear and DDLGender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding `DDLTestApearnce` in your sample, but are getting the error (and setting the selected value) on `DDLTesttoAppear`.

Comment: At times some typing mistake can make life hell! I will be more careful on that